# Need to change HTML structure so it will work with a script I am using

Tags: html, validation

I am using a form validation script, which, if I have data-validation as required:true (as I do below) then when the user submits the form the validation script will stop the form from submitting and highlight the invalid form fields in red (by adding "has-error" to the parent container).

So in the code below, "has-error" gets added to the input-group div.

```
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cost" id="cost" data-validation='{"required": true}' data-fieldname="{% trans %} cost {% endtrans %}" />
            </div>
            <span class="help-block">{% trans %} overview {% endtrans %}</span>
```

**The problem:** the help-block doesn't get coloured red, because it's not part of the input-group container.

If I move the help-block into the input-group, the layout gets destroyed. Changing the validation script for this one case seems like overkill to.

**So my question:** is there an equivalent CSS/HTML layout I can use to get the same result, but by having the help-block within the container so that upon an error it also goes red.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show css file for your example?

Comment: It's just using the twitter-bootstrap css. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it'll be working or not but you can move help-block into the input-group and use positioning by CSS like that:

```
.help-block {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;

}
.group-relative {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Here the example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwu75gnx/1/)

Comment: I have just one word to describe that answer.............. legendary. Thanks so much, that works perfectly!!